# Java/Android: getHostName() is always null with InetSocketAddress

Tags: java, android, ports, gethostbyname, inet-socket

I am using an Android app using a open source java library (Calimero). My code tries to get the Hostname and the Port using this code:

```
private static KNXNetworkLinkIP connect(InetSocketAddress isaLocalEP, InetSocketAddress isaRemoteEP)
  {
    KNXNetworkLinkIP netLinkIp = null;

    int serviceMode = KNXNetworkLinkIP.TUNNEL; // tunnel to IP router
    boolean useNAT = true; // NAT not used for PC true or false , but needed for emulator = true
    KNXMediumSettings tpSettings = new TPSettings(true); // TP1 medium

    try
    {
      // Output the local end point address

      if (m_debugOutput == true)
      {
        System.out.println("..Tunneling, NAT ignored, TP1 medium");

        // Should be the PC's VPN address

        System.out.print("..Local  EP:");
        System.out.println(isaLocalEP.getHostName() + ":" + isaLocalEP.getPort());

        System.out.print("..Remote EP:");
        System.out.println(isaRemoteEP.getHostName() + ":" + isaRemoteEP.getPort());

        System.out.print("..useNAT:");
        System.out.println(useNAT);

        System.out.println();
      }

      netLinkIp = new KNXNetworkLinkIP(serviceMode, isaLocalEP, isaRemoteEP, useNAT, tpSettings);
    }
    catch (KNXLinkClosedException e)
    {
      System.out.println("connect:KNXLinkClosedException = " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (KNXFormatException e)
    {
      System.out.println("connect:KNXFormatException = " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (KNXException e)
    {
      System.out.println("connect:KNXException = " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("connect:Exception = " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return netLinkIp;

  } // connect(isaLocalEP, isaRemoteEP)
```

The problem is in this line:

```
  netLinkIp = new KNXNetworkLinkIP(serviceMode, isaLocalEP, isaRemoteEP, useNAT, tpSettings);
```

Here the code for KNXNetworkLinkIP

```
   /*
    Calimero - A library for KNX network access
    Copyright (C) 2006-2008 W. Kastner

    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
    Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
*/

package tuwien.auto.calimero.link;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import tuwien.auto.calimero.CloseEvent;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.FrameEvent;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.GroupAddress;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.IndividualAddress;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.KNXAddress;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.Priority;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.cemi.CEMIFactory;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.cemi.CEMILData;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.cemi.CEMILDataEx;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.exception.KNXException;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.exception.KNXIllegalArgumentException;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.exception.KNXTimeoutException;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.knxnetip.KNXConnectionClosedException;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.knxnetip.KNXnetIPConnection;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.knxnetip.KNXnetIPRouter;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.knxnetip.KNXnetIPTunnel;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.link.event.NetworkLinkListener;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.link.medium.KNXMediumSettings;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.link.medium.PLSettings;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.link.medium.RFSettings;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.link.medium.TPSettings;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.log.LogManager;
import tuwien.auto.calimero.log.LogService;

/**
 * Implementation of the KNX network link based on the KNXnet/IP protocol, using a
 * {@link KNXnetIPConnection}.
 * <p>
 * Once a link has been closed, it is not available for further link communication, i.e.
 * it can't be reopened.
 * <p>
 * If KNXnet/IP routing is used as base protocol, the send methods with wait for
 * confirmation behave equally like without wait specified, since routing is an
 * unconfirmed protocol. This implies that no confirmation frames are generated, thus
 * {@link NetworkLinkListener#confirmation(FrameEvent)} is not used.
 * <p>
 * IP address considerations:<br>
 * On more IP addresses assigned to the local host (on possibly several local network
 * interfaces), the default chosen local host address can differ from the expected. In
 * this situation, the local endpoint has to be specified manually during instantiation.
 * <br>
 * Network Address Translation (NAT) aware communication can only be used, if the
 * KNXnet/IP server of the remote endpoint supports it. Otherwise, connection timeouts
 * will occur. With NAT enabled, KNXnet/IP accepts IPv6 addresses. By default, the
 * KNXnet/IP protocol only works with IPv4 addresses.<br>
 * 
 * @author B. Malinowsky
 */
public class KNXNetworkLinkIP implements KNXNetworkLink
{
    /**
     * Service mode for link layer tunneling.
     * <p>
     */
    public static final int TUNNEL = 1;

    /**
     * Service mode for routing.
     * <p>
     */
    public static final int ROUTER = 2;

    private static final class LinkNotifier extends EventNotifier
    {
        LinkNotifier(Object source, LogService logger)
        {
            super(source, logger);
        }

        public void frameReceived(FrameEvent e)
        {
            final int mc = e.getFrame().getMessageCode();
            if (mc == CEMILData.MC_LDATA_IND) {
                addEvent(new Indication(new FrameEvent(source, e.getFrame())));
                logger.info("indication from " + ((CEMILData) e.getFrame()).getSource());
            }
            else if (mc == CEMILData.MC_LDATA_CON) {
                addEvent(new Confirmation(new FrameEvent(source, e.getFrame())));
                logger.info("confirmation of "
                    + ((CEMILData) e.getFrame()).getDestination());
            }
            else
                logger.warn("unspecified frame event - ignored, msg code = 0x"
                    + Integer.toHexString(mc));
        }

        public void connectionClosed(CloseEvent e)
        {
            ((KNXNetworkLinkIP) source).closed = true;
            super.connectionClosed(e);
            logger.info("link closed");
            LogManager.getManager().removeLogService(logger.getName());
        }
    };

    private final int mode;
    private volatile boolean closed;
    private final KNXnetIPConnection conn;
    private volatile byte hopCount = 6;
    private KNXMediumSettings medium;

    private final LogService logger;
    // our link connection event notifier
    private final EventNotifier notifier;

    /**
     * Creates a new network link based on the KNXnet/IP protocol, using a
     * {@link KNXnetIPConnection}.
     * <p>
     * For more details on KNXnet/IP connections, refer to the various KNXnet/IP
     * implementations.<br>
     * 
     * @param serviceMode mode of communication to open, <code>serviceMode</code> is one
     *        of the service mode constants (e.g. {@link #TUNNEL}); depending on the mode
     *        set, the expected local / remote endpoints might differ
     * @param localEP the local endpoint of the link to use;<br> - in tunneling mode
     *        (point-to-point), this is the client control endpoint, use <code>null</code>
     *        for the default local host and an ephemeral port number<br> - in
     *        {@link #ROUTER} mode, specifies the multicast interface, i.e. the local
     *        network interface is taken that has the IP address bound to it (if IP
     *        address is bound more than once, it's undefined which interface is
     *        returned), the port is not used; use <code>null</code> for
     *        <code>localEP</code> or an unresolved IP address to take the host's
     *        default multicast interface
     * @param remoteEP the remote endpoint of the link to communicate with;<br> - in
     *        tunneling mode (point-to-point), this is the server control endpoint <br> -
     *        in {@link #ROUTER} mode, the IP address specifies the multicast group to
     *        join, the port is not used; use <code>null</code> for
     *        <code>remoteEP</code> or an unresolved IP address to take the default
     *        multicast group
     * @param useNAT <code>true</code> to use network address translation in tunneling
     *        service mode, <code>false</code> to use the default (non aware) mode;
     *        parameter is ignored for routing
     * @param settings medium settings defining device and medium specifics needed for
     *        communication
     * @throws KNXException on failure establishing link using the KNXnet/IP connection
     */
    public KNXNetworkLinkIP(int serviceMode, InetSocketAddress localEP,
        InetSocketAddress remoteEP, boolean useNAT, KNXMediumSettings settings)
        throws KNXException
    {
        switch (serviceMode) {
        case TUNNEL:
            InetSocketAddress local = localEP;
            if (local == null)
                try {
                    local = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 0);
                }
                catch (final UnknownHostException e) {
                    throw new KNXException("no local host available");
                }
            conn = new KNXnetIPTunnel(KNXnetIPTunnel.LINK_LAYER, local, remoteEP, useNAT);
            break;
        case ROUTER:
            NetworkInterface netIf = null;
            if (localEP != null && !localEP.isUnresolved())
                try {
                    netIf = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(localEP.getAddress());
                }
                catch (final SocketException e) {
                    throw new KNXException("error getting network interface: "
                        + e.getMessage());
                }
            final InetAddress mcast = remoteEP != null ? remoteEP.getAddress() : null;
            conn = new KNXnetIPRouter(netIf, mcast);
            break;
        default:
            throw new KNXIllegalArgumentException("unknown service mode");
        }
        // initialize our link with opened connection
        mode = serviceMode;
        logger = LogManager.getManager().getLogService(getName());
        notifier = new LinkNotifier(this, logger);
        conn.addConnectionListener(notifier);
        // configure KNX medium stuff
        setKNXMedium(settings);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new network link based on the KNXnet/IP tunneling protocol, using a
     * {@link KNXnetIPTunnel} with default communication settings.
     * <p>
     * The link is established using a KNXnet/IP tunnel, the local endpoint is the default
     * local host, the remote endpoint uses the default KNXnet/IP port number, network
     * address translation (NAT) is disabled.
     * 
     * @param remoteHost remote host name
     * @param settings medium settings defining device and medium specifics needed for
     *        communication
     * @throws KNXException on failure establishing link using the KNXnet/IP connection
     */
    public KNXNetworkLinkIP(String remoteHost, KNXMediumSettings settings)
        throws KNXException
    {
        this(TUNNEL, null, new InetSocketAddress(remoteHost, KNXnetIPConnection.IP_PORT),
            false, settings);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new network link based on the KNXnet/IP routing protocol, using a
     * {@link KNXnetIPRouter}.
     * <p>
     * 
     * @param netIf local network interface used to join the multicast group and for
     *        sending, use <code>null</code> for the host's default multicast interface
     * @param mcGroup address of the multicast group to join, use <code>null</code> for
     *        the default KNXnet/IP multicast address
     * @param settings medium settings defining device and medium specifics needed for
     *        communication
     * @throws KNXException on failure establishing link using the KNXnet/IP connection
     */
    public KNXNetworkLinkIP(NetworkInterface netIf, InetAddress mcGroup,
        KNXMediumSettings settings) throws KNXException
    {
        conn = new KNXnetIPRouter(netIf, mcGroup);
        // initialize our link
        mode = ROUTER;
        logger = LogManager.getManager().getLogService(getName());
        notifier = new LinkNotifier(this, logger);
        conn.addConnectionListener(notifier);
        // configure KNX medium stuff
        setKNXMedium(settings);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see tuwien.auto.calimero.link.KNXNetworkLink#setKNXMedium
     * (tuwien.auto.calimero.link.medium.KNXMediumSettings)
     */
    public void setKNXMedium(KNXMediumSettings settings)
    {
        if (settings == null)
            throw new KNXIllegalArgumentException("medium settings are mandatory");
        if (medium != null && !settings.getClass().isAssignableFrom(medium.getClass())
            && !medium.getClass().isAssignableFrom(settings.getClass()))
            throw new KNXIllegalArgumentException("medium differs");
        medium = settings;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see tuwien.auto.calimero.link.KNXNetworkLink#getKNXMedium()
     */
    public KNXMediumSettings getKNXMedium()
    {
        return medium;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see tuwien.auto.calimero.link.KNXNetworkLink#addLinkListener
     * (tuwien.auto.calimero.link.event.NetworkLinkListener)
     */
    public void addLinkListener(NetworkLinkListener l)
    {
        notifier.addListener(l);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see tuwien.auto.calimero.link.KNXNetworkLink#removeLinkListener
     * (tuwien.auto.calimero.link.event.NetworkLinkListener)
     */
    public void removeLinkListener(NetworkLinkListener l)
    {
        notifier.removeListener(l);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see tuwien.auto.calimero.link.KNXNetworkLink#setHopCount(int)
     */
    public final void setHopCount(int count)
    {
        if (count < 0 || count > 7)
            throw new KNXIllegalArgumentException("hop count out of range [0..7]");
        hopCount = (byte) count;
        logger.info("hop count set to " + count);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see tuwien.auto.calimero.link.KNXNetworkLink#getHopCount()
     */
    public final byte getHopCount()
    {
        return hopCount;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc} When communicating with a KNX network which uses open medium,
     * messages are broadcasted within domain (as opposite to system broadcast) by
     * default. Specify <code>dst null</code> for system broadcast.
     */
    public void sendRequest(KNXAddress dst, Priority p, byte[] nsdu)
        throws KNXLinkClosedException, KNXTimeoutException
    {
        send(dst, p, nsdu, false);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc} When communicating with a KNX network which uses open medium,
     * messages are broadcasted within domain (as opposite to system broadcast) by
     * default. Specify <code>dst null</code> for system broadcast.
     */
    public void sendRequestWait(KNXAddress dst, Priority p, byte[] nsdu)
        throws KNXTimeoutException, KNXLinkClosedException
    {
        send(dst, p, nsdu, true);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see tuwien.auto.calimero.link.KNXNetworkLink#send
     * (tuwien.auto.calimero.cemi.CEMILData, boolean)
     */
    public void send(CEMILData msg, boolean waitForCon) throws KNXTimeoutException,
        KNXLinkClosedException
    {
        doSend(adjustMsgType(msg), waitForCon);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see tuwien.auto.calimero.link.KNXNetworkLink#getName()
     */
    public String getName()
    {
        // do our own IP:port string, since InetAddress.toString() always prepends a '/'
        final InetSocketAddress a = conn.getRemoteAddress();
        return "link " + a.getAddress().getHostAddress() + ":" + a.getPort();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see tuwien.auto.calimero.link.KNXNetworkLink#isOpen()
     */
    public boolean isOpen()
    {
        return !closed;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see tuwien.auto.calimero.link.KNXNetworkLink#close()
     */
    public void close()
    {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (closed)
                return;
            closed = true;
        }
        conn.close();
        notifier.quit();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        return getName() + (mode == TUNNEL ? " tunnel" : " routing") + " mode"
            + (closed ? " (closed), " : ", ") + medium.getMediumString()
            + " medium hopcount " + hopCount;
    }

    private CEMILData adjustMsgType(CEMILData msg)
    {
        final boolean srcOk = msg.getSource().getRawAddress() != 0;
        // just return if we don't need to adjust source address and don't need LDataEx
        if ((srcOk || medium.getDeviceAddress().getRawAddress() == 0)
            && (medium instanceof TPSettings || msg instanceof CEMILDataEx))
            return msg;
        return (CEMILDataEx) CEMIFactory.create(srcOk ? null : medium.getDeviceAddress(),
            null, msg, true);
    }

    private void send(KNXAddress dst, Priority p, byte[] nsdu, boolean confirm)
        throws KNXTimeoutException, KNXLinkClosedException
    {
        final CEMILData f;
        final short mc = mode == TUNNEL ? CEMILData.MC_LDATA_REQ : CEMILData.MC_LDATA_IND;
        final IndividualAddress src = medium.getDeviceAddress();
        // use default address 0 in system broadcast
        final KNXAddress d = dst == null ? new GroupAddress(0) : dst;
        final boolean tp = medium.getMedium() == KNXMediumSettings.MEDIUM_TP0
            || medium.getMedium() == KNXMediumSettings.MEDIUM_TP1;
        if (nsdu.length <= 16 && tp)
            f = new CEMILData(mc, src, d, nsdu, p, true, hopCount);
        else
            f = new CEMILDataEx(mc, src, d, nsdu, p, true, dst != null, false, hopCount);
        doSend(f, confirm);
    }

    private void doSend(CEMILData msg, boolean waitForCon) throws KNXTimeoutException,
        KNXLinkClosedException
    {
        if (closed)
            throw new KNXLinkClosedException("link closed");
        if (medium instanceof PLSettings) {
            final CEMILDataEx f = (CEMILDataEx) msg;
            if (f.getAdditionalInfo(CEMILDataEx.ADDINFO_PLMEDIUM) == null) {
                f.addAdditionalInfo(CEMILDataEx.ADDINFO_PLMEDIUM, ((PLSettings) medium)
                    .getDomainAddress());
                logger.trace("send - added PL additional info to message");
            }
        }
        else if (medium.getMedium() == KNXMediumSettings.MEDIUM_RF) {
            final CEMILDataEx f = (CEMILDataEx) msg;
            final RFSettings rf = (RFSettings) medium;
            if (f.getAdditionalInfo(CEMILDataEx.ADDINFO_RFMEDIUM) == null) {
                final byte[] sn =
                    f.isDomainBroadcast() ? rf.getDomainAddress() : rf.getSerialNumber();
                // add-info: rf-info (0 ignores a lot), sn (6 bytes), lfn (=255:void)
                f.addAdditionalInfo(CEMILDataEx.ADDINFO_RFMEDIUM, new byte[] { 0, sn[0],
                    sn[1], sn[2], sn[3], sn[4], sn[5], (byte) 0xff });
                logger.trace("send - added RF additional info to message "
                    + (f.isDomainBroadcast() ? "(domain address)" : "(s/n)"));
            }
        }
        try {
            logger.info("send message to " + msg.getDestination()
                + (waitForCon ? ", wait for confirmation" : ""));
            logger.trace("cEMI " + msg);
            conn.send(msg, waitForCon ? KNXnetIPConnection.WAIT_FOR_CON
                : KNXnetIPConnection.WAIT_FOR_ACK);
            logger.trace("send to " + msg.getDestination() + " succeeded");
        }
        catch (final KNXConnectionClosedException e) {
            logger.error("send error, closing link", e);
            close();
            throw new KNXLinkClosedException("link closed, " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I already checked with the Debugger the values given to the method they are:

```
isaLocalEP = /169.254.96.102:12345
isaRemoteEP = /169.254.96.33:3671
```

So they are not null.

Any ideas? Maybe some problems with IPv4 or IPv6?

*LogCat using getAddress().getHostAddress()*

```
11-07 10:04:12.800: W/System.err(14989): tuwien.auto.calimero.exception.KNXException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)
11-07 10:04:12.805: W/System.err(14989):    at tuwien.auto.calimero.knxnetip.ConnectionImpl.connect(ConnectionImpl.java:369)
11-07 10:04:12.805: W/System.err(14989):    at tuwien.auto.calimero.knxnetip.KNXnetIPTunnel.<init>(KNXnetIPTunnel.java:117)
11-07 10:04:12.805: W/System.err(14989):    at tuwien.auto.calimero.link.KNXNetworkLinkIP.<init>(KNXNetworkLinkIP.java:179)
11-07 10:04:12.805: W/System.err(14989):    at com.example.connectiontest.KNXNetwork.connect(KNXNetwork.java:149)
11-07 10:04:12.805: W/System.err(14989):    at com.example.connectiontest.KNXNetwork.connect(KNXNetwork.java:122)
11-07 10:04:12.805: W/System.err(14989):    at com.example.connectiontest.KNXNetwork.tryConnecting(KNXNetwork.java:80)
11-07 10:04:12.805: W/System.err(14989):    at com.example.connectiontest.HelloKNXNetwork.connect(HelloKNXNetwork.java:67)
11-07 10:04:12.805: W/System.err(14989):    at com.example.connectiontest.HelloKNXNetwork.onClickActivity(HelloKNXNetwork.java:42)
11-07 10:04:12.805: W/System.err(14989):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 10:04:12.805: W/System.err(14989):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-07 10:04:12.805: W/System.err(14989):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3111)
11-07 10:04:12.805: W/System.err(14989):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3644)
11-07 10:04:12.805: W/System.err(14989):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14313)
11-07 10:04:12.805: W/System.err(14989):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-07 10:04:12.805: W/System.err(14989):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-07 10:04:12.805: W/System.err(14989):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-07 10:04:12.805: W/System.err(14989):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
11-07 10:04:12.805: W/System.err(14989):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 10:04:12.810: W/System.err(14989):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-07 10:04:12.810: W/System.err(14989):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
11-07 10:04:12.810: W/System.err(14989):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
11-07 10:04:12.810: W/System.err(14989):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

*LogCat using Port 0*

```
11-07 10:16:32.085: W/System.err(17185): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-07 10:16:32.090: W/System.err(17185):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
11-07 10:16:32.090: W/System.err(17185):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:175)
11-07 10:16:32.090: W/System.err(17185):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:463)
11-07 10:16:32.090: W/System.err(17185):    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:182)
11-07 10:16:32.090: W/System.err(17185):    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:287)
11-07 10:16:32.090: W/System.err(17185):    at tuwien.auto.calimero.knxnetip.ConnectionImpl.connect(ConnectionImpl.java:360)
11-07 10:16:32.090: W/System.err(17185):    at tuwien.auto.calimero.knxnetip.KNXnetIPTunnel.<init>(KNXnetIPTunnel.java:117)
11-07 10:16:32.090: W/System.err(17185):    at tuwien.auto.calimero.link.KNXNetworkLinkIP.<init>(KNXNetworkLinkIP.java:179)
11-07 10:16:32.090: W/System.err(17185):    at com.example.connectiontest.KNXNetwork.connect(KNXNetwork.java:148)
11-07 10:16:32.090: W/System.err(17185):    at com.example.connectiontest.KNXNetwork.connect(KNXNetwork.java:121)
11-07 10:16:32.090: W/System.err(17185):    at com.example.connectiontest.KNXNetwork.tryConnecting(KNXNetwork.java:79)
11-07 10:16:32.090: W/System.err(17185):    at com.example.connectiontest.HelloKNXNetwork.connect(HelloKNXNetwork.java:67)
11-07 10:16:32.090: W/System.err(17185):    at com.example.connectiontest.HelloKNXNetwork.onClickActivity(HelloKNXNetwork.java:42)
11-07 10:16:32.090: W/System.err(17185):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 10:16:32.090: W/System.err(17185):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-07 10:16:32.095: W/System.err(17185):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3111)
11-07 10:16:32.095: W/System.err(17185):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3644)
11-07 10:16:32.095: W/System.err(17185):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14313)
11-07 10:16:32.095: W/System.err(17185):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-07 10:16:32.095: W/System.err(17185):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-07 10:16:32.095: W/System.err(17185):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-07 10:16:32.095: W/System.err(17185):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
11-07 10:16:32.095: W/System.err(17185):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 10:16:32.095: W/System.err(17185):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-07 10:16:32.095: W/System.err(17185):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
11-07 10:16:32.095: W/System.err(17185):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
11-07 10:16:32.095: W/System.err(17185):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Why the forward slash before the IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have an IP address, but no host name! Try this:

```
 System.out.println(isaLocalEP.getAddress().getHostAddress() + ":" + isaLocalEP.getPort());
```

Comment: Now it is not null anymore. But the next Object is also null you have an idea? I edited my main post and added the declaration

Comment: Which exactly is the 'next Object'? The next similar line, with 'isaRemoteEP'?

Comment: `netLinkIp = new KNXNetworkLinkIP(serviceMode, isaLocalEP, isaRemoteEP, useNAT, tpSettings);` and netLinkIp is `null` .

Comment: @Mr.Mojo This can not happen! A constructor never returns null! It either returns an instanec of the specified class, or throws an exception. Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: The following exception is thrown: `catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("connect:Exception = " + e.getMessage());
    }` with this output: `connect:Exception = null`. After debugging I mentioned that it is thrown after the code line in my post before.

Comment: This is why you should **never ever again** use System.out.println() to log exceptions!!!! Use e.printStackTrace() , or a proper logging tool, like Log4J. Use printStackTrace, and copy the output in the question, that will help us to help you

Comment: True words! This code is not up to date I will improve it in next time. I have added the logcat output in my main post!

Comment: @Mr.Mojo Ok, now the problem is clear: the port you are trying to bind to is already bound, some program already uses it... I don't know if you have `netstat` on your device, it might require root too, but if you can do a `netstat -a | grep LISTEN` you can get a list of used ports - so you can choose one that is still free...

Comment: I changed my Port to "0" which means any port is chosen. Then I recieve the logcat output below in my main post

Comment: Marked it as solved because you answered the main problem with getHostName(). Thank you!